# Простой пример для varArgs: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет, имеется пример на python

```
def foo1(*args):
    print args
def foo2(**kwargs):
    print kwargs
foo1(1, 2, 3)
foo2(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

Но он не работает вот сообщение:

[image: изображение ошибки]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы используете Python 3, в котором, в отличие от Python 2, `print` - не выражение, а функция. Поэтому правильно будет `print(args)`.